# 500 Internal error при вызове метода API

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

Проблема в следующем: на платформе asp mvc 5 развернуто приложение, у которого есть некоторый api. При попытке вызова методов api и передаче в качестве аргумента сложного объекта (структура, модель) возникает ошибка *500 internal error*. При передаче простых типов данных *(int,string)* подобное не наблюдается. Подскажите, куда можно копать, может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

```
public class testModel 
{
  public string arg { get; set; } 
}

[HttpPost, Route("testStruct")] 
public IHttpActionResult CompleteSignUpWorker(testModel tmodel) 
{
  if (tmodel == null) 
    return BadRequest("Arguments is null"); 
  return Ok(); 
}
```

Comment: Покажите код? И что за сложный объект, он несериализируемый?

Comment: Более менее разобрался, но теперь стало понятно, что объект не передается. Первая проблема с 500 ошибкой решилась добавлением Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded в загаловок post запроса. Но при обработке метода возникает ошибка nullreferenceexception. Вот код

Comment: <pre>public class testModel
        {
            public string arg { get; set; }
        }


        [HttpPost, Route("testStruct")]
        public IHttpActionResult CompleteSignUpWorker(testModel tmodel)
        {
            if (tmodel == null) return BadRequest("Arguments is null");
            return Ok();
        }<code>

Comment: Прошу прощения, не получается оформить в блок кода.

Comment: откомпилируйте и запустите Debug версию - StackTrace исключения укажет Вам конкретную строку кода, в которой происходит ошибка

Comment: Проблема в том, как передаются параметры запроса. Может быть заголовок запроса или что то похожее влияет на то, как сервер преобразует входные данные и связывает с моделью.

Comment: и как же  передаются параметры запроса?

Comment: Под API чаще всего подразумевается SOAP, если это SOAP, то у вас Content-Type  не правильный, и отсутствуют другие параметры заголовков которые нужны SOAP. А всётаки, что вы имеете ввиду под словом API?

Comment: @nick_n_a под API чаще всего понимается REST JSON. Особенно когда речь идет о ASP.NET WebApi

Comment: nick_n_a прав, ошибка была в загаловке.